# Parse.com Custom cell boolean

Tags: ios, boolean, parse-platform

I am stuck for a long time with boolean show/hide image. Image is placed in my cell. Only boolean is needed. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Parseclass"];
    [query whereKey:@"imagebool" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
        cell.discounts.hidden =YES;
        }else{
        cell.discounts.hidden =NO;
        }
    }];
```

EDIT:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"parsecell"];
    [query whereKey:@"imagebool" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *object, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", object);
             NSDictionary *dict = [object objectAtIndex:0];
             BOOL boolean;
             boolean = [[dict objectForKey:@"imagebool"] boolValue];
             if(boolean==YES)
             {
                  NSLog(@"BOOL1: %hhd", boolean);
                 cell.discounts.hidden = YES;
             } else {
                 cell.discounts.hidden = NO;
                 NSLog(@"BOOL2: %hhd", boolean);
             }


         }
         else
         {

             NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below stuff :-

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]] //No need for this double encoding.
```

Simple go with [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES].

Also

```
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
 {
    if (!error && objects) //Checking for object's just to know if your getting any result for condition that you provided in query.
    {
      //Then hide your image.
    }else{
      //Or show your image.
    }
}];
```

Just in case if your storing image on parse and check if image is nil or stored. Then just simple call for column that is storing image and no boolean check condition. That way you would get object's and know which row/column in your app is to show/hide image. Also in that object you will get image and provide it in your app and no need to store on local memory of phone. Anything else do let me know.

UPDATE:-

As you will get the object(array).

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *object, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", object);
         NSDictionary *dict = [object objectAtIndex:0];
         //Now with dict you could simply check for key(boolean) and then depending on YES/NO ,you could hide/Show the image.
     }
     else
     {       
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }
 }];
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Ops, The first stuff I just forgot to delete. But about the second one, I have the an imageview firmly placed in the cell. And just want to check boolean, not placed image in parse database.

Comment: Could you tell me a bit about your flow ,that way I would be able to suggest to an appropriate answer. Means I don't understand why u keeping bool in parse as you could store image there ,this way u would save local memory and also for uploading part ,you could use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#installation) it would let u uploading in parallel without affecting UI interaction of user.

Comment: I am having UITableview with one Custom cell filled with Countries. Inside the cell I have some labels and 2 imageview. 1st one is just pic of country using URL SDWebImage and the second one is an image in the cell. Some kind of "I Suggest" image which I have placed in my app. And I just want to hide or not according to the boolean T/F on Parse. Do you understand my problem now?

Comment: I have upated my post check the "updated" part. So the resulting array you get from parse in objects(array) you could use that array and pull out dict from that and with that dict you see if bool is yes or no using objectForKey. So at end hide or show as per Yes/No.

Comment: Can you check my edit, please? Bool is returning only Yes(1), nothing else.

Comment: And it will take 1 API each cell? isn`t there any way, how to reduce?

Comment: So value of boolean depends on what you have stored on parse. So if it's yes there then it will return yes only.

Comment: For reduce ,you could create a function which would be called before reload and will hit the parse url store all boolean value's from there into a local store then when you call reload you could use that array(having boolean values) for hide or show. So its a standard way to call and store all in one go rather than call same parse every time.

Comment: Also tick this post as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see with your code:

1. For some reason you're double encoding `YES`, i.e. `[NSNumber numberWithBool:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]`, probably won't break things, but fix it
2. In the block you're checking for an error, but you're not checking the `objects` returned. The array will come back empty if nothing matched the query, add a check for `objects.count > 0`